# Unable to use rand() function in php 7.3 if the digit number more than 10?

Tags: php

I just upgrade my PHP from 5.6 to 7.3. I have a function that generate random number with range 100000000 to 99999999999. This is seems fine when i tried to used this function in PHP 5.6, but when i tried to used this function in PHP 7.3 it's return nothing.

NO error or other warning. I have tried to used `print_r`, `echo`, and `var_dump` but it's still got no result. What's going on here ?

what i tried was like `rand(1000000000,99999999999)` and `mt_rand(1000000000,99999999999)`, its return nothing, no error and such like that, just empty result.

Comment: Please show your code, so we can see how you're using it.

Comment: @aynber edited question

Comment: [I'm not having any problems with it](https://3v4l.org/FNNcA).

Comment: How about random_int ?

Comment: @AndriiFilenko i tried to used the number more than or equals to 10 digit number, it will return NULL if i give vardump... i dunno why